# No me deja ejecutar ionic serve

Tags: angular, ionic

Hola muy buenas actialice la version de angular hoy para generar mi proyecto en una pwa al darme un error actualice el proyecto y ahora no me deja haber nada. He hecho un dowgrade de angular y angular cli pero no me deja.

Este es el error que me da:

```js
[ng] This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^9.0.0-beta || >=9.0.0 <10.0.0,
[ng] but Angular version 8.2.14 was found instead.
[ng] Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
[ng] https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 3).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: Vuelve a instalar los paquetes npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debes actulizar ionic cli, cordova, y Angular --->
 `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic`    `sudo npm install ionic` `npm install @angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias de ante mano.
contextualizar por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.
origen del proyecto:
desde windows con ionic 4
destino del proyecto para continuar trabajando.
ubuntu 20.4
ionic 6.x

error al intentar ionic server : código 13

intente los comandos indicados en ubuntu y asunto solucionado, corrió sin problemas.
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm install ionic
npm install @angular/cli

muchas gracias.